# Laravel - login over SSL-Proxy

Tags: ssl, laravel, proxy

I try to login (simple form with email/password) over an SSL-Proxy: https://www.ssl-account.com/heregoesmyadress but it don't work. Laravel always redirects my to the start page. If I use login without the proxy everything works fine. Does anyone know how I can manage this?

Comment: Does the proxy allow cookies?

Comment: Hi, yes the proxy allow cookies!